# MVC Double Encoding MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

*Caveat: I have an MVC site as an area in a .Net WebForms site. I'm explaining that in advance in the case that it sheds light on my issue.*

Now the issue I am having is that I am routing values that could contain special characters like an `apostrophe` (single quote). If i do not encode the value it routes properly however, my `Kendo MVC Grid` creates a invalid template when using the unencoded single quote as a filter.

```
http://{base}/{area}/{controller}/{view}?customerName=Justin's%20Instance - Throws Invalid Template Error

http://{base}/{area}/{controller}/{view}?customerName=Justin&#39;s%20Instance - No Error
```

So I thought the easiest solution was to properly encode my querystring parameter prior to passing it as a route value. That resulted in a double encoding situation. Then I found out about `MvcHtmlString.Create` which is specifically designed to tell the routing system not to re-encode the string value. However, it is still double encoding.

```
var customerNameEncoded = MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(model.Name));

var routeResult = RedirectToAction("ManageCustomer", new { customerName = customerNameEncoded });

return routeResult;
```

This is the Url that is created:

```
http://{base/{area}/{controller}/{view}?customerName=Justin%26%2339%3Bs%20Instance
```

As you can see the ' is being encoded again. This is throwing the following error.

```
> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException   A potentially dangerous
> Request.QueryString value was detected from the client
> (customerName="Justin&#39;s Instance").
```

The `web.config` for the MVC area has the following tag: `validateRequest="false"`

The `web.config` for the overall website has the following: `httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"`

Any ideas as to why this string is being double encoded and how to stop it from doing so?

Comment: If you are using MVC you should decorate your function with [ValidateInput(false)] .... I am looking at the two links you are saying one throws template error and the other doesn't.  However, they look the same.  Was this on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different types of encoding mixed here.
One is the HTML encoding which creates those &39; escape sequences.
Second is URL encoding which makes the %20 escape sequences.

I don't know what Kendo MVC Grid is by I think I know what the result of your action should be. Try this code

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customerNameEncoded = "Justin's Instance";
        var url = Url.Action("ManageCustomer", new { customerName = customerNameEncoded });
        return Redirect(url);
    }

    public ActionResult ManageCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerName = customerName;
        return View();
    }
```

If you stop the Index method just before it returns you'll see that url content is

```
"/Home/ManageCustomer?customerName=Justin%27s%20Instance"
```

what is the properly encoded URL.

You can also check what you get as customerName in ManageCustomer action and you'll see it's

```
"Justin's Instance"
```

Don't get confused by what you may see in the browser's address bar. Some browsers (like Firefox) do not show the encoded URL and may show something like ".../ManageCustomer?customerName=Justin's Instance"

Comment: The browser was in fact encoding it properly, however the Kendo Grid was the eventual culprit. Ended up spinning my wheels on the one wrong thing for too long. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Query string parameters are URL-encoded, not HTML-encoded. (`%` notation, rather than `&#` entities)

2) The config settings `validateRequest` and `requestValidationMode` apply to ASP.Net WebForms, not MVC. You must add the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to the controller methods, as Bryan commented.